# how could I get this URL from XHR

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

I wanna get this URL from this [Page](https://www.holonis.com/excellenceaddiction/o/bydze8ztg) with Requests.

URL I want to get: `https://www.holonis.com/api/comments/5ae3cfc82eebca0025b9890c/post`

Answer (score 1):

You can get a request via requests.get:

```
import json
import requests

## Fetch the page
resp = requests.get(url)

## Load it into a dict
node = json.loads(resp.text)
```

You can then get the comments from the node, or other info, like so:

```
comments = [element['body'] for element in node['items']]
```